# OData / WCF Data Service - HTTP 500 Error

Tags: wcf, http, odata

I have created an OData/WCF service using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP SP3 with all current patches installed.

When I click on "view in browser", the service opens and I see the 3 tables from my EF model.  However,  when I add a table name ("Commands" in this case) to the end of the query string, rather than seeing the data from the table, I get an HTTP 500 error.
*(This error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you are visiting had a server problem which prevented the webpage from displaying.)*.

I have not only followed the examples from 2 sites, but have also tried running the sample application that the blog poster sent me (that works on his machine), and still am not having any luck.

The blog post is at [Exposing OData from an Entity Framework Model](https://web.archive.org/web/20101216021748/http://infinitecodex.com/post/2010/06/10/Exposing-OData-from-an-Entity-Framework-Model.aspx)

Does anyone have an idea why this is occurring and how to resolve it?

## Here is the output of the "View in Browser":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <service xml:base="http://localhost:1883/VistaDBCommandService.svc/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
- <workspace>
  <atom:title>Default</atom:title> 
- <collection href="Commands">
  <atom:title>Commands</atom:title> 
  </collection>
- <collection href="Databases">
  <atom:title>Databases</atom:title> 
  </collection>
- <collection href="Statuses">
  <atom:title>Statuses</atom:title> 
  </collection>
  </workspace>
  </service>
```

---

## Update:

In an effort to get this working, I have:

1. Removed and re-installed IIS
2. Ran the %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis –i –enable command
3. Ran the %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\ServiceModelReg.exe -r command.
4. Created a new solution and followed the instructions very carefully to assure that I 
   didn't mess anything up.

After all of this, I am still getting the same HTTP 500 error, with no entries of any kind in the Event Viewer.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I figured out that my problem was an issue with opening the database.  The way I figured it out was to add the following to the servicename.svc.cs file in the InitializeService method:

`config.UseVerboseErrors=true;`

Thanks to all who tried to help.

Eric

Answer (score 5):

Please try these debugging tips to see the actual error which happened:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308172942/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

`config.UseVerboseErrors=true;` helped me in finding out the problem. The problem was I was using windows authentication for database connection. After changing to SQL Server Authentication everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

`500` always means there was an unhandled exception in the service. Go look in the windows event log to see what that error was.

Comment: John,
I do not have any entries in the Event log.  To make sure, I cleared the existing events (all Information - none related to the app) and then re-ran the app.  Same results, no entries in the event log.

Eric

Comment: Yes, I am running it locally on my dev system.

Eric

Comment: I updated the initial post to indicate what steps I have taken since my last post.

Answer (score 2):

Received similar output with VS2013:

[image: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error screenshot]

Resolved by upgrading the Entity Framework.

See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21028123/2116188.

Answer (score 1):

You can also activate Failed Request Tracing for your Web Application in IIS

then you will get detailled trace execution in Xml files from IIS when a 500 error occurs

There is a good article here explaining how to setup Failed Request Tracing in IIS :

[Using Failed Request Tracing to Trace Rewrite Rules](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/467/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules/)

HTH
Cédric

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server Compact data file (Like NorthWind.sdf) you need to give write file permission to IUSRS group.

Ex: If you are using NorthWind.sdf in DataDirectory i.e. YourWeb/App_Data then you need to give **write permissions** to _IUSRS group from IIS Console or from Windows Explorer.